# Directly comparing two column values in Fusion Tables map display

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've got an unlisted Fusion Table with sample election data and vote counts by Wisconsin county, and I'm building a maps display page for election night.  I'd like to conditionally style the county polygons depending on which candidate has a higher vote count, but I can't seem to do any styling based on a WHERE clause which directly compares column values.  Instead, the default styling takes effect and the where clauses never kick in.

My reading of the [FT "SQL-ish" syntax](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference#Select) makes me think that it doesn't allow a WHERE clause which directly compares two columns, so maybe that's what's stopping me ... but man, I'd very much like to.  Is there a technique I'm missing?

Vote counts for candidate 1 are in "1_Vote_Count" and for candidate 2 in "2_Vote_Count".

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function initialize () {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.824708,-89.780273),
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          zoomControl: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
          },
          panControl: false,
        });

        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '173CovMDpzEwyBBtF2fwkxHB5nt6zETzBzG-3YLE',
            where: "Office_ID = 'G' AND FIPS_Code > 0"
          },
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
              fillColor: "#00FF00",
              fillOpacity: 0.3,
              strokeWeight: 0.5
            }
          }, {
            where: "'1_Vote_Count' < '2_Vote_Count'",
            polygonOptions: {
              fillColor: "#DD0000"
            }
          }, {
            where: "'2_Vote_Count' < '1_Vote_Count'",
            polygonOptions: {
              fillColor: "#0000DD"
            }
          }]
        });

layer.setMap(map);

}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are correct that it is not possible to compare two columns of your table. You could select the value first, but this is a very ugly solution.

Comment: I ran a quick test which confirms Odi comment. You could request a feature: http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/list?q=Type%3DFeature_Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no technique that you're missing. I recommend opening a feature request, as Eric noted.

http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/list?q=Type%3DFeature_Request

Comment: Ah, well.  Figured it couldn't hurt to ask.  Thanks, Kathryn!